# Send in the second condition can not work in php to submit its result to the android

Tags: php, android

I wrote the following code. Because the `java` code sends the data by `POST` method, so the first condition in the `php` file should not be performed and the second condition should be performed. But I can not see the result of the `echo "$name";` in android.But when I use the `POST` instead the `GET` in first condition, I can see the result of the first condition in android.

```
 public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Get user defined values
        Name = fname.getText().toString();
        Email   = email.getText().toString();
        Login   = login.getText().toString();
        Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/reg.php");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
        content.setText( text  );

    }
```

And

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {     
$name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);
       $user   = urldecode($_POST['user']);
       $email  = urldecode($_POST['email']);
       $pass   = urldecode($_POST['pass']);

       print " ==== POST DATA =====
       Name  : $name
       Email : $email
       User  : $user
       Pass  : $pass"; 

 }
else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { echo "$name"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php, $name is defined inside the if clause.

declare it outside.

```
$name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {   

..
}
else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { echo "$name"; }
```